# Return storyboard cell size or ignore collectionview on sizeForItemAt delegate method

Tags: ios, swift

I saw this question asked on one other post, however, the answer was unsatisfactory.

I have a view controller with several collection views in it for which I size their cells perfectly with the storyboard. However, there is one collection view in particular that I need to size manually so I included the method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to override or ignore this methods for all collection views but that last one.

I tried using the following code suggested on the other post, but it crashes at runtime:

```
if collectionView != interestsCollectionView {
            return self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout(), sizeForItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
        }
```

Any ideas of how I might accomplish this?

Comment: can you post what the crash is ? What does it say

Answer (score 1):

I guess this

```
 return self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout(), sizeForItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
```

will recursively call the same method many times resulting in a crash caused by the loop , plus if you implemented this method `sizeForItemAt` then you'll have to return a value for the other collections also as the `if` here `if collectionView != interestsCollectionView`  may never hit from the compiler logic , so you may do

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
  if collectionView == collectionView1 {
     return CGSize(width:<#w#>,height:<#h#>)
  }
  else if collectionView == collectionView2 {
     return CGSize(width:<#w#>,height:<#h#>)
  }
  else { } // etc
}
```